# How do I make a counter similar to iter tools cycle except that instead of 0,1,2,0,1,2 it goes 01,2,1,0,1,2,1,0,etc... in Python?

Tags: python, counter, python-itertools, cycle

I am trying to make an iterator that goes "backwards" too. Itertools cycle provides a similar function cycle(range(3)) and the next function produces 0,1,2,0,1,2. However, I would like 0,1,2,1,0,1,2,1,0,1,2....

I tried using iter tools cycle. Here is the code.

```
from itertools import cycle
myIterator = cycle(range(3))

print(next(myIterator))
print(next(myIterator))
print(next(myIterator))
print(next(myIterator))
```

Output:
0
1
2
0

Answer (score 3):

Just pass the sequence you want to cycle to `cycle`:

```
it = cycle([0, 1, 2, 1])
```

For an arbitrary list, you can use

```
from itertools import cycle, islice
forward_list = list(range(5))

it = cycle(forward_list + forward_list[-2:1:-1])

print(list(islice(it, 15)))
```

which outputs

```
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 3, 2, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 3, 2, 0]
```

Comment: I see, this works, but now I am trying to generalize it. E.g.  n=5 --> 0,1,2,3,4,5,4,3,2,1,0,1,etc..

Comment: I have got it,list1 = cycle(list(chain(list(range(0,n)),list(range(n,0,-1))))) this will accomplish what was in the title.(Edit: using n-1 may be necessary in some cases.)

Comment: @JohnB FWIW, just `cycle(chain(range(0,n),range(n,0,-1)))` would do. Or something like `cycle(l + l[-2:1:-1])` where `l` is the forward list.

Answer (score 1):

You could write a function that returns the infinite generator that cycles up and down using chain and cycle from itertools:

```
from itertools import chain,islice,cycle

def upDown(N): return cycle(chain(range(N),range(N-2,0,-1)))
```

output:

```
from itertools import islice
print(*islice(upDown(5),17))

0 1 2 3 4 3 2 1 0 1 2 3 4 3 2 1 0
```

If you don't want to import anything, the function can be a generator itself using basic constructs:

```
def upDown(N):
    while True:
        yield from range(N)
        yield from range(N-2,0,-1)
```

If you don't mind the cycle starting on its highest value, you can write the function like this:

```
def wave(N):
    while True:
        yield from map(abs,range(1-N,N-1))
```

output:

```
print(*islice(wave(5),17))

4 3 2 1 0 1 2 3 4 3 2 1 0 1 2 3 4

print(*islice(wave(5),4,21))

0 1 2 3 4 3 2 1 0 1 2 3 4 3 2 1 0
```